# Why do my sessions persist on other pages when visited manually but not when following a link?

Tags: php, html, session

I created a user account system for my website using PHP sessions and mySQL.  I have been trying for SO LONG to get it to work right.  The very first night it worked 'mostly' right.  And I have made almost no progress since then.  I've been researching and googling until I've burnt out, and I haven't figured it out.

The problem is, I can create user accounts fine, and it registers as planned in my sql database, and I can even login correctly.  However, when I go to other pages on my site, the session doesn't seem to be registered on those pages.  I check for the user's session with

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

and if they are not logged in, a 'login' button appears in main menu on every page.  If they are logged in, a button with their username appears that links to their account page.  If you would like to see for yourself, www.glorygamer.com is the website and you can use testAccount with password as the password to login and see.

Here's the weird part.  Today I made a discovery, and now I am CERTAIN it isn't a problem with my PHP script.  If I manually enter in the page I want to visit (if I literally type "www.glorygamer.com/account_home.php" then it works perfectly.  The session always starts properly with any page I visit in this way.  However, when I click on links in my menu, it seems to work almost at random.  Sometimes I will be sent to the next page and the session will be started correctly, and sometimes it won't be.

Is there some special way I need to link my pages, even though they all correctly session_start() before anything else?

Here is the login script:

```
<?php session_start();
//pass info to mysql(servername, username, password)
$connect = mysql_connect ("localhost", "***", "***");
if (!$connect) 
{
        die ('Failed to connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ggstudio_accountDatabase", $connect);

//capture data sent to page through login
//usernameField and passwordField

$usernameSubmission = $_POST['usernameField'];
$passwordSubmission = $_POST['passwordField'];

$validAccount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userAccounts WHERE userID = '$usernameSubmission' AND userPassword = '$passwordSubmission'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($validAccount);
if (($row['userID'] == $usernameSubmission)&&($row['userPassword'] == $passwordSubmission))
{
/*********************************
**********************************
assign global variables to session
after starting session and then***
redirect to user homepage*********
**********************************
**********************************
*/
//get account number from database
$_SESSION['accountNumber']= $row['accountNumber'];
//get first name from database
$_SESSION['firstName']= $row['firstName'];
//get last name from database
$_SESSION['lastName']= $row['lastName'];
//save username into session
$_SESSION['username']= $row['userID'];
//save password into session (only really useful if user wants to change password)
$_SESSION['userPassword']= $row['userPassword'];
//get user's email address from database
$_SESSION['userEmail']= $row['userEmail'];
//get GP from database
$_SESSION['gpoints']= $row['userGloryPoints'];
//get user join date from database
$_SESSION['userJoinDate']= $row['userJoinDate'];
//get user rank
$_SESSION['userRank']= $row['userRank'];

session_write_close();
header('Location: http://www.glorygamer.com/account_home.php');
exit;
}
else
{
$loginFailed= TRUE;
setcookie("incorrectLogin", $loginFailed, time()+20);
session_write_close();
header('Location: http://www.glorygamer.com/shibboleth.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your PHP installation using session cookies? Can you try to find out what happens to them? Are you 1000% sure you have only one `session_start()` in each file? Can you show how you initialize the session?

Comment: I added the script used to log in the user (therein starting the session) to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It sucks, I am lacking 6 points for commenting on questions, thus I have to use an answer… In my tests it rather seemed your problem is script dependant as I cannot see the logged in status on the top right even if I am visiting another URL (e.g. www.glorygamer.com/index.php) from outside. That’s obviously clear, as there is nothing different between a link and the same URL without a link except the Referer header.

The only site which I can see my logged in status on is the mentioned www.glorygamer.com/account_home.php

The session cookie is always existing and sent (checked with Live HTTP Headers) and therefore must also be reiceved on index.php (where the username is not displayed in the top right corner, but instead "Login").

So you should check if session_start() really works in these files. Also check for posibble surpressed error messages, as session_start() would throw an error if there was any output before session_start() (either via echo, var_dump, print, print_r or pure HTML outside of PHP blocks). I am not sure if you can oppress that error messages, but I guess you can with the "right" server settings.

Hope my hints can get you a little further to your solution.

Comment: That is really strange.  On my computer, in any of the browsers I run in, I see the username displayed at the top for any webpage I visit, as long as I manually enter it.

I will need to look into enabling error messages.  I've never done that before, and I don't know how it works, but I'm sure I will have to learn to get to my goal.  

Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to the actual question, but nevertheless important:

**Please always escape any user-input data before passing it along to the database.** 
This:

```
$usernameSubmission = $_POST['usernameField'];
$passwordSubmission = $_POST['passwordField'];

$validAccount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userAccounts WHERE userID = '$usernameSubmission' AND userPassword = '$passwordSubmission'");
```

should read:

```
// Any data entered by a third party is insecure
$usernameInsec = $_POST['usernameField'];
$passwordInsec = $_POST['passwordField'];

// Protect your SQL statements
$validAccount = mysql_query(
                "SELECT * FROM userAccounts "
              . " WHERE userID = '" . mysql_escape_string( $usernameInsec ) . "' "
              . "   AND userPassword = '" . mysql_escape_string( $passwordInsec ) 
              . "'"
              );
```

Comment: Thank you, I recently stumbled upon information on SQL injection and saw this.  I plan on having that, as well as password encrypting with a salt, before I give any users an account.  Definitely important.

Comment: Injection is an important issue. String ending marks such as " and ' and SQL keywords such as "or" and boolean logic that evaluates to true such as "or 1=1" is an easy and dangerous attack method. Useful link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#86791) on php.net sounds like a similar situation to the one you're in, though I don't know why `session_write_close` would cause the problem you're having.

Rather than replace with `session_regenerate_id()` as the comment suggests, I'd recommend you simply remove `session_write_close()` to see if this bears fruit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the only place that goes to another page with a header call is the script i listed above, which already calls session_write_close().  All of the other instances are simply html links, not php at all.

I added the session_write_close() recently, because it never seemed to log in correctly on the first try, and this fixed that problem.  But the remaining problem is recalling the session on other pages on the site.

Comment: Interesting... can you check your pages in your editor and see if a byte order mark is being written at the start of the files? This is usually invisible in your editor, but PHP would interpret this as a few characters at the start of your script and any output before `session_start()` will prevent the session from starting. This could be on any script included before your `session_start()` call.

Comment: Great.  How do I check for that? (I haven't actually heard of a byte order mark before...)

Comment: Oh wait, isn't that a unicode signature, or something of the sorts?  Those are not present in any of my files ran on the website.

Comment: I'd suggest using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script to see if any errors are being hidden. If this comes up dry, I'd suggest double checking for the presence of the BOM with certain editors, as I've not come across a session problem like this historically that wasn't related to an error or some premature output. You can try this one: http://www.unipad.org/download/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I put    error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of the script, but I do not know where errors (if any) are displayed.

Comment: I would also add something strange I discovered. The correct session being registered or not isn't dependent on the PAGE, but the link that brings me to that page. There are two different links in my main menu that will bring you to your account page, if you are logged in. One of these ALWAYS works correctly, and one NEVER works correctly. Further, the about link on the main menu never works correctly either. The home buttons will link to the index with the right session variables if you are linking from a page with the correct session, and they won't if you are coming from a page that isn't.

Comment: Again ALL of the pages work ALL of the time (at least for me, on any browser) if the page is entered manually in the browser rather than entered through a link.

Comment: Also, the editor you had me install did not find any characters before the <? session_start();